# Have installed Babel for german language. Application run in Eclipse is now german, but exported as "Eclipse product" is still english

Tags: java, eclipse, internationalization, eclipse-rcp

I'm currently migration an Eclipse RCP application from 3.0 to 4.4. The application uses a lot of custom actions (extending the class `Action`). Those actions are all german, because I am able to use my own language-files.
But the application also uses the action `RESET_PERSPECTIVE` of the class `ActionFactory`. Because this is a system action, I can't manually set the text. Also the title bar of the about window is in english.

Therefore I have installed the german babel language pack. Now, my Eclipse itself is in german language and when I run the application in Eclipse using my Run configuration, the application is entirely in german. But when I export the application as Eclipse product, the `RESET_PERSPECTIVE` action and the title bar of the about dialog are still in english.

**My Run configuration**

Program arguments: -os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl} -consoleLog

VM arguments: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 -Xms40m -Xmx512m

**Arguments of the .product-file**

Program arguments:
-os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -nl de_DE -consoleLog

VM arguments:
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 -Xms40m -Xmx512m
-Duser.language=de -Duser.country=DE

I also tried to add some of the nl_plugins to the dependencies of my .product-file, but I don't know which one to pick and if I try to add all I get the error message:

```
Processing inclusion from feature
org.eclipse.pde.container.feature: Bundle org.eclipse.core.filesystem.java7.nl_de_4.4.0.v20150804
100819 failed to resolve:
Host plug-in org.eclipse.core.filesystem.java7_0.0.0 has not been found.
```

But I'm not even shure if this is the proper way to do this.

**EDIT**

I also tried to run the launcher of my Eclipse product from the command line using `productname.exe -nl de` but that didn't work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, you need to add the ".nl_de" fragments to your product configuration.

Your build does probably not contain those (you can check in the output "plugins" directory). So all the language parameter will not help.

The error your getting is because you added a ".nl_de" fragment (org.eclipse.core.filesystem.java7.nl_de...) and the host bundle (org.eclipse.core.filesystem.java7) is not part of the configuration. So you have to remove this fragment from the product configuration. Maybe others as well.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. After adding all the ".nl_de" fragments, I had to remove four of them. You said that I get the error-message because I added (org.eclipse.core.filesystem.java7.nl_de) and the host bundle (org.eclipse.coe.filesystem.java.7) is missing. But this wasn't the case. It was part of the configuration. That's a little strange. But anyway, it works.